# Android Studio Gradle build error : "Reference must start with '@': "

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

while  build the project. I get the following error: 
Reference must start with '@':

Error :
build failed

"Reference must start with '@': "

Detailed error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Reference must start with '@': 
        at android.databinding.tool.ext.ExtKt.parseXmlResourceReference(ext.kt:108)
        at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutModel.readableName(BaseLayoutModel.kt:143)
        at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutModel.fieldName(BaseLayoutModel.kt:115)
        at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutModel$COMPARE_FIELD_NAME$1.compare(BaseLayoutModel.kt:29)
        at android.databinding.tool.writer.BaseLayoutModel$COMPARE_FIELD_NAME$1.compare(BaseLayoutModel.kt:27)
        at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
        at kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysJvmKt.sortWith(_ArraysJvm.kt:1772)........
..............
```

i put the gradle builder error in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/dfeverx/7cbed1f2c72778946ed0592478dce728)

please anyone help me

Comment: Don't use a gist `there`, post the layout here and the error as well, use the [help about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to make it look nice.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini while  building, it   failed with an error message:" build failed Reference must start with '@': "
then in the detailed error log  is pretty big   thats why i put that in a gist
and it is not pointing to any particular class or layout file in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling a component that does not have the correct reference for example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="ImgView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
 ..../>
```

correct way

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImgView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
 ..... />
```

You must verify in which part of the xml the reference is not being made correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your xml files for an empty id